# What is the "Reconstruction" trait in reference to Pathfinder Elans?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, races, racial-traits

While reading the [GitP Vitalist Handbook](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?222365-PF-Mental-Medicine-a-Vitalist-Handbook), I came across the following line in the Elans entry in the Races section:

> The Reconstruction trait is golden for Elan Vitalists, allowing you to continue to heal even while unconscious and making a huge portion of your list more powerful than normal.

I was unable to identify any [traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits) or [Elan racial traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/races/elan) (standard or alternate) named "Reconstruction". Does anyone here know what trait the guide is referring to, and where to find the reference for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this thread](http://dreamscarredpress.com/dragonfly/ForumsPro/viewtopic/t=2182.html) on the Dreamscarred Press forums Jeremy Smith, listed as an author of [*Ultimate Psionics*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/124281/Ultimate-Psionics), posted the alpha version of the elan's alternate racial traits, including the alternate racial trait reconstruction, which says that

> Some elans are more adept at psionically rebuilding bodies than preserving them. These elans may spend 1 or more pp as a swift action to gain Fast Healing 2 for a number of rounds equal to the number of pp spent; this can be used even when unconscious. The elan also gains a +1 bonus to its manifester level when manifesting powers of the Healing subdiscipline. This trait replaces Resistance and Resilience.

I couldn't determine if this alternate racial trait was subsequently included in [*Ultimate Psionics*](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/products/ultimate-psionics).